# key error while trying to pass data as a parameter using a json file

Tags: python, json, file, io

code is given below
import time
import unittest
import logging as log
from loggenerator import set_log_params,move_latest_log_to_persistent_file
from parse_test_json import get_test_params
from scrapping import SC

```
    class ScrapeTest(unittest.TestCase):
        def setup(self):
            self.start_time=time.time()
        def teardown(self):
            self.end_time=time.time()
        def test_SC_scrape(self):
            try:
                test_name="test scrape"
                set_log_params(log_file=test_name,level=log.INFO)
                log.info("step1:set all test params")
                test_params = get_test_params(self.__class__.__name__, test_name=test_name)
                log.info("step 2:set")
                ik=SC()
                log.info("step3:calling scrapper for")
                log.debug(ik.parseURL(party_name=test_params["party_name"],start_date=test_params["start_date"],end_date=test_params["end_date"]))

            except Exception as e:
                raise e
            move_latest_log_to_persistent_file(log_file=test_name)
```

####

```
    import json, os
    from builtins import *
    def get_test_params(test_class_name = None, test_name = None):
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        file_path = "/test_param_jsons/" + test_class_name + "params.json"
        json_file = dir_path + file_path
        with open(json_file) as test_data:
            test_json = json.load(test_data)
            return test_json[test_class_name][test_name]
```

this function is raising error `key error`.

Answer (score 0):

this should work as long as you have a json file available at: `<SCRIPT_PATH>/test_param_jsons/MyClass_params.json`

Also, in order to avoid `KeyError` you'll need to ensure that your input json file contains key: value, `test_class_name : test_name`

```
import json, os
from builtins import *

class MyClass:
        def get_test_params (self, test_class_name = None, test_name = None):
              with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"test_param_jsons\\params.json"), 'r') as test_data:
                        test_json = json.load (test_data)
                        try:
                                return test_json[test_class_name][test_name]
                        except KeyError as e:
                                print ('KeyError: {}'.format (e))


        def mymain(self, test_name):
                ''' mymain is defined to accomodate your requirement to use __class__ as a parameter '''
                test_params = self.get_test_params (self.__class__.__name__, test_name = test_name)
                return test_params


if __name__ == '__main__':
        test_name = 'sth' 
        myclass = MyClass ()
        result = myclass.mymain (test_name)
        print (result)
```

Comment: that's because you there is a missing \ right before `test_param‌​_jsons` in the path: `C:\\Users\\chandan\\workspace\\testpythonproject\test_param‌​_jsons\\MyClass_para‌​ms.json`. all backslashes should be doubled, you need to change the line below to accommodate it:                 `json_file = '{}/test_param_jsons/{}_params.json'.format (os.path.dirname (os.path.realpath (__file__)), test_class_name)`

Comment: I an able to read but key error is coming
{'party_name': 'Ram lal', 'start_date': 2016, 'end_date': 2017}
======================================================================
test_params = get_test_params(self.__class__.__name__,   Fi File "C:\Users\chandan\workspace\testpythonproject\parse_test_json.py", line 8, in get_test_params
    return test_json[test_class_name][test_name]
KeyError: 'ScrapeTest'

Comment: `line 8, in get_test_params return test_json[test_class_name][test_name] KeyError: 'ScrapeTest` that means your json file is missing keyname: ScapeTest! your logic requires that the key: `test_class_name` and value: `test_name` be present in the json file.

Comment: @cssd1983, No. I suggest you refer to Stack Overflow help pages regarding the use of website. SO is here to guide you in understanding your problems and answering your **specific question**. SO is not here to do your homework/projects for you.